# How to detect single cell change in AgGrid when using full row editing?

Tags: ag-grid-angular

I am using AgGrid 25.0.1 Enterprise version and typically use editType=fullrow in my application. However I would like to be able to detect when a user changes the value of one cell and then tabs to another, so that I can update one of the dropdowns. There is a callback cellValueChanged but it only fires when row editing stops and then it sends all the events at one time. I would like to know when a cell loses focus before actually saving the row. Is this possible?

For background, if I don't use fullrow editing I can get a cellValueChanged event as each cell is changed but then I would have to make a separate HTTP call to save the results for each cell or create some workaround to wait until the user says it is OK to save all the changes.

Comment: Hi, did you got any solution for this ? I am stuck in the same problem